# Rails Uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't figure out this error that I'm getting:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::SessionHelper):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3:in `<class:ApplicationController>'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

This is my Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionHelper
end
```

And my sessions_helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spelling error

```
include SessionsHelper
```